# .Net Core - Multiple requests to service with different response callbacks

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asynchronous, callback, microservices

So I am currently developing a web application (.NET Core 2.1) that is making multiple asynchronous requests to a service.

From JavaScript, I am formulating and making the requests that will later on be picked up by my specified controller/method:

[JavaScript requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZx7Y.png)

[Methods in controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjltT.png)

Each one of the functions in my controller sends a request to a service.

Once the service has completed processing the request, a callback function is triggered in my web application where I can access the response and send it back to my client:

[Callback function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHEFI.png)

My problem is that each one my requests has a different response-callback assigned to it and I need to wait for it to be called before I can proceed and get the response value and return it to my client.

Because the requests are asynchronous, I tried implementing threads and using ManualResetEvent/AutoResetEvent to make the threads wait for the callbacks to be triggered and then release them after I have assigned the responses; however, I haven't been successful in doing so since whenever I stop blocking one of the threads to let the following one run and reach its callback; all threads get released causing the "return" in my controller-method to be triggered before having the chance to populate my returned object (callback is triggered **after** I have sent the response to my client causing my response to be null/empty).

Any ideas on how to approach this?

The whole process is:

1) The client creates a request and sends it to RabbitMQ.

2) Rabbit picks up the request and sends it to any service listening to that type of request.

3) The service picks up the request, processes it, creates a response object and sends it to Rabbit.

4) Rabbit gets the response and sends it to all clients listening to that type of response.

5) My client (listening to that type of response) gets the response through a callback method and then I can return whatever value(s) my service sent.

Comment: Why just not make a single end point that takes both the Guid and the InstallationId, then make two Task methods and do a ContinueWith() in your controller? or in your JS, since it is probably an Ajax call, put the second call in the success function of the first request

Comment: Why aren't you just using async/await? This is way more work than necessary for a modern application to handle asynchronous work.

Comment: My service is a docker service that is listening to a queue (RabbitMQ). The whole process is: 1) The client creates a request and sends it to RabbitMQ. 2) Rabbit picks up the request and sends it to any service listening to that type of request. 3) The service picks up the request, processes it, creates a response object and sends it to Rabbit. 4) Rabbit gets the response and sends it to all clients listening to that type of response. 5) My client (listening to that type of response) gets the response through a callback method and then I can return whatever value(s) my service sent.

Comment: Using async will not work because of the callback method

Answer (score 0):

You have to integrate these two calls. They can be integrated into your controller as a single API method. Furthermore, you can also do it on a frontend side, just use promises to do it.
If one task depends on the result of another, there will not any advantages of using threads. Because the second one is not running until the first one will return a result, they are executed synchronously.
There are two examples how u can do this:

c# ex.:

```
public async ActionResult GetBla([fromquery]int id){
var t1 = await doThis(id); /// or use ContinueWith(result=> ....
var t2 = await doThat(t1.id);
}
```

js ex.:

```
$http.get("someurl")
  .then(result=> $http.get("anotherurl"+ result.id))
```

Comment: This would work but I am not looking to nest my requests since they do not depend one another

Comment: If they don't have dependiencies u can run them like this  on a frontend: Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then((values) =>{
  console.log(values);
}); or run two tasks on a bakend and wait their responses.